# Get Path of material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the path of material from my script but it returns empty. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public GameObject obj;

public void Start(){
  Debug.Log(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(obj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material));
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from the docs but maybe you need to assign the material to a variable first rather use `GetComponent` within the call. It would help debug anyway as you can then check the object and material are not null.

Comment: BTW if you intent is to switch shaders at runtime - _[don't!....."Unity creates a **copy of a material** when you access `renderer.material` for the first time"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48560246/585968)_

Comment: Yes it creates an instance, could that be the issue that it returns empty string?

Comment: You're missing the point.  Regardless of your intent you should be careful of whatever it is you plan to do with `GetComponent<Renderer>().material`.  You might have 2 instances of that shader now, or perhaps more 1 for every game object running that script.

Comment: Try to avoid nesting too many calls into one.   What if `GetComponent` failed?