# Unity loop Application.EnterPlayMode

Tags: unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

When I hit Play Unity makes me wait infinite time before start the scene. The message in Hold On window is "Application.EnterPlayMode Waiting for Unity's code to finish executing". There is only one scene in URP with global volume, directional light and a plane with this script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PerlinNoise : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Resolution")]
    [Space]
    public int width = 256;
    public int heigth = 256;
    [Space]
    [Header("Adjustments")]
    [Space]
    public float scale = 20;
    public float xOffset = 10;
    public float yOffset = 10;

 void Update()
 {
     Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
     renderer.material.mainTexture = GenerateTexture();
 }

 Texture2D GenerateTexture()
 {
     Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, heigth);

     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
     {
         for (int y = 0; x < heigth; y++)
         {
             Color color = GenerateColor(x, y);
             texture.SetPixel(width, heigth, color);
         }
     }

     texture.Apply();
     return texture;
 }

 Color GenerateColor(int x, int y)
 {
     float xCoord = (float)x / width * scale + xOffset;
     float yCoord = (float)y / width * scale + yOffset;
     float perlinNoise = Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord, yCoord);
     return new Color(perlinNoise, perlinNoise, perlinNoise);
 }
}
```

I tried to kill unity editor task in task manager and restart unity but the same issue repeats. Please help me

Comment: Seems like a limitation of the machine.

Comment: You are calling GetComponent && GenerateTexture in Update which executes everyframe...
those two itself will kill your processor because your memory will get full by no time.
You are even lucky to be able to play the game.

I would suggest you call those function once in Start

Comment: BTW, avoid using `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.xx = yy` because **Unity duplicates the material** and you will eventually run out of memory!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48560246/585968

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop inside your `GenerateTexture` method. Specifically, the condition in the nested loop (for `y`) is accidentally checking for `x`:

```cs
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; x < heigth; y++) // x < height SHOULD BE y < height
    {
        Color color = GenerateColor(x, y);
        texture.SetPixel(width, heigth, color); // this should probably be (x, y, color)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good spot! +1  Though the OP's use of `renderer.material.mainTexture = xxx` will lead to [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559523/how-can-i-switch-between-shaders-in-real-time).  No doubt he will discover it once he has applied your fix.  ;)

Comment: So, I tried and there is no loop, but the script doesn't generate the noise map as expected

Comment: @Gabriele did you try my suggestion to change `texture.SetPixel(width, height, color);` to `texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);` ?